# Fully display background image

Tags: css

I'm setting up a site, and want to create a responsive background image but I'm getting only single line with background image. What property should i need to use to  make the entire background image to fit?

I created 2 files, 
index.html :

```
<div id="logo">Test</div>
```

style.css :

```
#logo {
background-image: url("bg.png");
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried many times but only single line gets background image. I want the background image to be fully displayed on screen without using height property which i think makes site less responsive.

Comment: The background is dependent of the `<div>` height, so you need to give the `<div>` some height value.... Or you can remove the image as background and insert an `<img>` (with `width: 100%` and `height: auto`) inside the `<div>`. This would require you to put the text **over** the image.

Comment: Your div has height set by its child, `Test`, the height of that is the line height supplied to the text. If you want it full screen, there are many ways to do it. Read up about flex boxes in css, or just supply `height: 100vh` to the div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to have the same height as the screen you can use `height:100vh`. But if you want only the image full size you can do this like this :

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#image{
max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528920304568-7aa06b3dda8b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
<div id="text">test</div>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the div is a block element by default and he's not changed the `display` property, so it has 100% width of its parent already.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the height of logo div and set it as full height by adding height:100% for the body and logo div, your code should look like below code

```
html, body
{
   height: 100%;
}
#logo {
   background-image: url("bg.png");
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   height:100%;
}
```